# OSX 10.7 Lion Screen Sharing, cannot Switch to virtual display from snow leopard 10.6 client

Tags: macos, osx-lion, screen-sharing

I installed Lion, and would like my other computers (macs and PCs) to connect to virtual displays on the mac pro. Preferably with the ability to stream sound and video through this session.

I enabled Remote Management on the Lion machine, but when I am using a Snow Leopard computer and click "Share Screen", it does not give me the option of which display to use, it connects me to the primary display just like a normal VNC client used to do on a leopard machine with screen sharing enabled.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably could try some third-party app such as [GoToMeeting](http://www.gotomeeting.com/fec/) and [GoMeetNow](http://www.gomeetnow.com/). They both have mac version.

Answer (score 0):

For Remote Management in OS X you need Apple Remote Desktop app to be able to connect to it.

The built it option is OS X is just a normal VNC.

I would strongly recommend TeamViewer, is way cheaper than GoToMeeting, faster and it's fully functional on the free option or if you prefer the paid option just pay once and get a lifetime license.